# How to call plugin function per site in a multisite?

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions, multisite

**My goal is to be able to call a plugin function per site and of course it has different result based on the site data.**

e.g.

I have a plugin called: **sample-plugin.php**

Inside it has a function called:

```
function sp_echo_site()
{
   echo get_site_url();
}
```

I have a multisite inside has 3 sites: e.g. animals.com, fruits.com and people.com

And in a network level, I wanted to call the `sp_echo_site()` function.

I wanted to do the following loop, however of course it doesn't work, 
How can I make this work?

```
foreach (get_sites() as $site)
{
   $site->sp_echo_site();
}
```

How can i achieve the following result?:

```
animals.com
fruits.com
people.com
```

Is this possible? Or do I have to go to database? Or any other alternative methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there...

If you have this in your plugin:

```
function sp_echo_site() {
   echo get_site_url();
}
```

Then you call this function as this:

```
sp_echo_site();
```

And this line will run this function in the context of current site.

So you'll have to do something like this:

```
if ( function_exists( 'get_sites' ) ) {
    foreach ( get_sites() as $site ) {
        switch_to_blog( $site->blog_id );

        sp_echo_site();

        restore_current_blog();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was stuck on this for hours, Thank you so much sir, your answer is spot on.

Answer (score 0):

Mark, to achieve the following result, you have to change your foreach loop. Try this code:

```
foreach (get_sites() as $site) {
  echo $site->__get('siteurl');
}
```

EDIT: [Wordpress reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Site/__get/)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that's an option OR you can do this
exmaple.com/?trigger_my_func
sub1.exmaple.com/?trigger_my_func or exmaple.com/sub1/?trigger_my_func
by triggering a method when accessing a subsite within a network it should run in the context of that site and output site specific information.